# How to check grammar in RStudio?

Tags: rstudio

OK, my first question.

I have to write my homework in RStudio and I am using Rmarkdown to have a nice output. My mother's tongue is not English, so I have some trouble with grammar sometimes. Spelling check is working well (just hit F/ and let it go through), but I don't find something for grammar. Is there a way to bring software like Grammarly and similar into RStudio? I googled and I didn#t found something. I would prefer an open-source grammar checker.

A few examples:

He walk to School.

I Know RStudio is cool.

Coefficient can be tricky to be interpret.

I know that in first sentence walk must be converted to walks.

In second sentence Know must be written as know.

In the third sentence, Coefficient needs a The in the beginning and must be written lowercase.

In websites like this, I am writing with Grammarly.

Comment: https://github.com/ropenscilabs/gramr

Comment: Just an observation about the third sentence, particularly if you are intending to correct grammar programmatically. Aside from the word "be" needing to be omitted, that sentence could be interpreted more than one way. It could be "The coefficient can be tricky to interpret." as you correctly identify, but "The coefficient could be tricky to interpret." and "Coefficients can be tricky to interpret." could also be valid.

Answer (score 3):

There is not a base R solution. There is a solution for Rmd or md documents:

```r
devtools::install_github("ropenscilabs/gramr")

write_good_ip() # run the write-good linter on text in a currently active Rmd file in RStudio

write_good_file("my_file.Rmd") # run the write-good linter on text in an Rmd file (RStudio not required)

run_grammar_checker("example.rmd") # run the write-good linter interactively

# Example output: 

#   index offset                              reason
# 1    15     12 "been defined" may be passive voice
# 2    49      8       "suddenly" can weaken meaning
```